# No cerrar sesión cuando presiono f5

Tags: angular

Tengo un HostListener para manejar las sesiones cuando se cierran las pestañás y el navegador de esta forma:

```
@HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    localStorage.clear();

  }
```

Pero me gustaría que al presionar f5 siga en la sesión, como puedo lograrlo?

Comment: Intenta discriminar usando el evento que pasas como argumento, algo debe cambiar cuando recargas, que cuando cierras la ventana

Comment: @joskarhernandez entiendo, tiene alguna propiedad o método para discriminar eso?

Comment: intenta imprimir en consola el evento

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que siga en la sesión seguir una estrategia en la que los datos de usuario se almacenen en el navegador usando por ejemplo `localStorage` y que al reentrar en la app se compruebe y se tome a todos los efectos como un usuario registrado con sesión activa. Siempre que se ajuste a tus requisitos, claro.

Answer (score 1):

Para ello te recomiendo usar localStorage guardando el token del usuario que inicia la sesión, a su vez también te recomiendo que uses Guardas en tu archivo de rutas para que verifique si el usuario está o no logueado de esa manera si lo está entonces te redirecciona a la página principal, sino te manda al login o a la página donde el usuario no está logueado.